# I'm trying to perform a number of commands in a batch file. I need to perform a process on a batch of .tiff files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to perform a sequence of commands in a batch file. I need to perform a process on a batch of .tiff files then move the output .tiff files to another location and perform another process on the original .tiff files. The code I am trying is below;

```
for %f in (*.tiff) do gdaldem_slope_batch.bat %~nf & move /-y "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\temp\*slope*.tiff" "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\trial" & for %f in (*.tiff) do gdaldem_hillshade_batch.bat %~nf & move /-y "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\temp\*hillshade*.tiff" "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\trial"
```

My problem is that it does the first command on the first file and moves it to the new location it then runs through the second command on all the files in turn and moves them to the new location. It then performs the first command on the second file and subsequently tries to run through the second command on all files attempting to create duplicates of the files already there.

Any advice, this is my first attempt at programming (incase you can't tell) so be gentle.

Thanks

Comment: If you using another batch file from within a batch file you need to use the CALL command to run the secondary batch file.  The syntax of your code says you are running this from the command line and not a batch file though.

Comment: Batch doesn't know, how you want your commands grouped. You do: `(loop1 :command A & command B & (loop2: command C & command D))`, but you probably want `(loop1 :command A & command B) & (loop2: command C & command D)`. You can actually use parantheses for your code. You write, you do it in a batchfile, but squashman is right: you use the syntax for commandline. Btw: don't try to write "one-liners" if not absolutely neccessary, especially, if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to perform a process on a batch of .tiff files then move the output .tiff files to another location and perform another process on the original .tiff files.

Here's how you want to group the commands then (also changed to `%%` batch file syntax):

```
for %%f in (*.tiff) do ( 
  call gdaldem_slope_batch.bat %%~nf 
  move /-y "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\temp\*slope*.tiff" "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\trial"
)
for %%f in (*.tiff) do (
  call gdaldem_hillshade_batch.bat %%~nf
  move /-y "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\temp\*hillshade*.tiff" "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\trial"
)
```

If you really wanted this on one line as in the question, though usually discouraged, that *can* be done by grouping the entire first `for` command as follows:

```
(for %%f in (*.tiff) do call gdaldem_slope_batch.bat %%~nf & move /-y "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\temp\*slope*.tiff" "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\trial") & for %%f in (*.tiff) do call gdaldem_hillshade_batch.bat %%~nf & move /-y "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\temp\*hillshade*.tiff" "C:\Users\wmiller\Desktop\trial"
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, you have made my life a lot easier.